# Cycles renders GlassBSDF opaque

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

I am trying to make a lens effect in Blender. I created the material for the lens with the Glass BSDF shader and connected it directly to the material output, and changed my render engine to Cycles. In the viewport everything looks fine:

[image: Cycles render in view]

But when I try to render the final image, the glass material becomes opaque. Is there any settings or something I could accidently have messed up? The final render looks like this:

[image: Cycles final render]

Comment: That looks more like a mesh that is in front of the camera blocking the view. Check that you don't have an object that is disabled for viewport, but that is enabled for rendering. Do't crop the images so tight so that they don't show the interface, or add more information about the scene.

Comment: Thanks. You were indeed right that I had a mesh blocking the view. It was hidden but showed up in the rendered image. I deleted it so everything is fine now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) **Reason # 12**

Comment: Yes, as you both have suggested - it was another object that was hidden that was blocking the view..